# Alamofire request to twilio swift

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, alamofire

I'm trying to get an SMS from twilio.com but get nil in response. Can anyone say what I'm doing wrong?

```
class SMSVerificationService: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = SMSVerificationService()


    func SMSRequest(countryCode:String, phoneNumber: String) {
        let accountSid = "ACc4d9785419f144412823ff20as34660c3d"
        let authToken = "4wqecx41f8999caa23735da214" // changed :)

        let url = URL(string: "https://\(accountSid):\(authToken)@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts\(accountSid)/Messages")
        print("url", url!)

        let parameters = [
            "To": "+37378847884",
            "From" : "+14243960339",
            "Body": "Hi daddy"
        ]
        Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: parameters,
                          encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseJSON { response in
                            let response = String(describing: response.result.value)
                            print(response)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What about checking the `response.result.failure`?

Comment: `responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})) `

Comment: Here we go, at least we have more informations. Do you mind doing `if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string}` and give us the printed text?

Comment: Data: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<TwilioResponse><RestException><Code>20404</Code><Message>The requested resource /2010-04-01/AccountsACc4d9785419f144412823ff2034660c3d/Messages was not found</Message><MoreInfo>https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404</MoreInfo><Status>404</Status></RestException></TwilioResponse>`

Comment: So: There is an error (what's telling Twilio) and the response is in XML, not JSON, that explain the previous `responseSerializationFailed()` message.

Comment: 404 maybe is telling something but not for me :)

Comment: "404": Known HTTP Error (You can search for it). "Th‌​e requested resource /2010-04-01/AccountsACc4d9785419f144412823ff2034660c3d/Messa‌​ges was not found" You can read that right? "20404": I'd guess I'd go on Twilio check what that means.

Comment: okay was a miss typo after "Accounts" forgot the `/`. but now its `A 'From' phone number is required.`

Comment: Are you building this as part of a server side app or an iOS/macOS app?

Comment: as I iOS part, why?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We do not recommend that you make requests to the Twilio API directly from your native application. To do so, you would need to store or retrieve your account SID and auth token in the application somewhere. If you do this, then a malicious attacker could get access to your credentials and abuse your Twilio account.

This is actually known as the [Eavesdropper vulnerability and was written about earlier this year](https://www.appthority.com/mobile-threat-center/blog/eavesdropper-mobile-vulnerability-exposing-millions-conversations/).

Instead we recommend that you create a web application and send the API requests from there. There is a blog post on how to do that here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/11/how-to-send-an-sms-from-ios-in-swift.html

I notice that your class is called `SMSVerificationService` too. If you are looking to build phone verification, then I recommend you take a look at the [Twilio Verify API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/verify/rest) that does a lot of the work for you.